# Bellman-Ford algorithm proof of correctness

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, correctness, proof-of-correctness

I'm trying to learn about Bellman-Ford algorithm but I'm stucked with the proof of the correctness. 
I have used [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm), but I simply can't understand the proof. I did not find anything on Youtube that's helpfull. 
Hope anyone of you can explain it briefly.  This page ["Bellman-ford correctness can we do better"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20024294/correctness-of-bellman-ford-algorithm-can-we-still-do-better) does not answer my question.

Thank you.

Comment: You may be better off posting this question to http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ - the stack exchange community dedicated to computer science theory.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see the problem from the perspective of dynamic programming of a graph with no negative cycle.

[image]

We can visualize the memoization table of the dynamic programming as follows:

[image]

The columns represent nodes and the rows represent update steps(node 0 is the source node), and the arrows directing from one box in a step to another in the next step are the `min` updates(step 0 is the initialization).

We choose one path from all shortest paths and illustrate why it is correct. Let's choose the 0 -> 3 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5. It is the shortest path from 0 to 5, we can choose any other one otherwise. We can prove the correctness by reduction. The initial is the source 0, and obviously, the distance between 0 and itself should be 0, the shortest. And we assume 0 -> 3 -> 2 is the shortest path between 0 and 2, and we are going to prove that 0 -> 3 -> 2 -> 4 is the shortest path between 0 and 4 after the third iteration.

First, we prove that after the third iteration the node 4 must be fixed/tightened. If node 4 is not fixed it means that there is at least one path other than 0 -> 3 -> 2 -> 4 that can reach 4 and that path should be shorter than 0 -> 3 -> 2 -> 4, which contradicts our assumption that 0 -> 3 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5 is the shortest path between 0 and 5. Then after the third iteration, 2 and 4 should be connected.

Second, we prove that that relaxation should be the shortest. It cannot be greater and smaller because it is the only shortest path.

---

Let's see a graph with a negative cycle.

[image]

And here is its memoization table:

[image]

Let's prove that at |V|'s iteration, here |V| is the number of vertices 6, the update should not be stopped.

We assume that the update stopped(and there is a negative cycle). Let's see the cycle 3 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 3.

dist(2) <= dist(3) + w(3, 2)
dist(4) <= dist(2) + w(2, 4)
dist(5) <= dist(4) + w(4, 5)
dist(3) <= dist(5) + w(5, 3)

And we can obtain the following inequlity from the above four inequalities by summing up the left-hand side and the right-hand side:

dist(2) + dist(4) + dist(5) + dist(3) <= dist(3) + dist(2) + dist(4) + dist(5) + w(3, 2) + w(2, 4) + w(4, 5) + w(5, 3)

We subtract the distances from both sides and obtain that:
w(3, 2) + w(2, 4) + w(4, 5) + w(5, 3) >= 0, which contradicts our claim that 3 -> 2 -> 4 -> 5 -> 3 is a negative cycle.

So we are certain that at |V|'s step and after that step the update would never stop.

My code is here on [Gist](https://gist.github.com/eduOS/fe9d258fd332aba60b8fe51842b6d7df).

Reference:

1. [dynamic programming - bellman-ford algorithm](https://downey.io/notes/omscs/cs6515/dynamic-programming-shortests-paths/)
2. [Lecture 14: Bellman-Ford Algorithm](https://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs161/cs161.1168/lecture14.pdf)